# Convex hull of a compact set of points is the convex hull of its boundary points?

Tags: general-topology

1. Convex hull of a compact set of points is the convex hull of its boundary points?

Is this true? How do you prove this in topology?

2. Also... is there a term in topology for the set of boundary points of a compact set that intersect their convex hull? I'm looking for something like "outer boundary" points... ie: the boundary points that don't include things like holes

Comment: The points that belong to the convex hull are called *extreme* points.

Comment: Thanks. That was the term I was looking for.

Comment: Krein Milman theorem.